# Copying a source directory using the command cp -rsf when target directory exists

Tags: symlink, cp, recursive

On `Centos 7`, when I use the command:

```
 cp -rsf /path/of/source /path/of/target
```

When the target directory exists, files would go to `/path/of/target/source`.

How can I avoid that?

**EDIT:**

1. source and target are directories.
2. Symlinks meet my environment needs. I need them to be symlink in order to save storage.

For example:

1. `mkdir /home/admin/test; mkdir /home/admin/test/1; touch /home/admin/test/1/1.txt;`
2. `mkdir /home/admin/test2; mkdir /home/admin/test2/1; touch /home/admin/test2/1/1.txt;`
3. `cp -rsf /home/admin/test/1 /home/admin/test2/1`
4. `ls /home/admin/test2/1`

**result is:**

`drwxrwxr-x 2 admin admin 4096 Sep 16 15:57 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin    0 Sep 16 15:56 1.txt`

**I wanted this result:**

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin 24 Sep 16 16:03 1.txt -> /home/admin/test/1/1.txt`

It means the source directory itself is copied within the target, but I wanted its content to be copied (Just like when the target directory doesn't exist)

Comment: how/why you want to copy from source to source?!!

Comment: see the example. it's not source to source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `-T`
according to [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)

`-T, --no-target-directory
treat DEST as a normal file`

```
cp -rsfT /path/of/source /path/of/target
```

if the target directory exists it copies symlinks in it. The benefit is if there are other files in target, they remain untouched.